# Caliburn Message Attach on Telerik RadGridView

Tags: .net, xaml, telerik, caliburn.micro, telerik-grid

I'm trying to use Caliburn Micro with Telerik's RadGridView. I'd like to send the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to my ViewModel using `Message.Attach`, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
<tel:RadGridView 
  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
  cal:Message.Attach="[Event AutoGeneratingColumn] = [Action AutoGeneratingColumn($dataContext)]"
 >
```

I use `Message.Attach` successfully elsewhere with the stock controls.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Usually result of the method signature you are using with Telerik controls

AutoGeneratingColumn($dataContext) is something that you would have written in your viewmodel, but it will probably complain or suppress the issue.  The event is actually looking for an $eventArgs passing.

`public void AutoGeneratingColumn(GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
}`

also keep in mind that anything 3rd party will need custom conventions in your bootstrapper, in the event that you are attempting anything x:Name on those controls.